# How to Jump into different method from another method when break statement is called

Tags: c#-4.0, break

Guys this is my problem,......

```
public void Method1()
{
      string[] cusID= {"SID001","SID002"};

      for (int k = 0; k < cusID.Length; k++ )
      {
          Process(staffId[k]); 
      }

}

    public void Process(string staffID)
    {
          Method2();
    }

    public void Method2()
    {
          for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
          {
              if(//condition is true)
              {
                   break;
              }
          }
    }
```

This is my sample code..guys i need to know how to jump into the 1st for loop when the break statement is execute. i tried goto statement but in doesn't work because it is only accessible for withing the block..can you please give any idea for me to solve this problem..

Thanks!!

Comment: What language is this? Please tag it. anyway, I doubt it allows you to break out of one function into something at global scope, which is what you have shown here, unless that is misleading.

Comment: When you break out of the second for loop, you would have returned to the process method which just returns to the 1st for loop. So what what is it you want, to start the 1st loop over again?

Comment: [Edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/31547475/edit) your question to include tags for what programming language and operating system you are using. Also, you should tell us [what you are trying to achieve](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/) as I don't understand what you think “to jump into a different method” will do.

Comment: Sorry guys im new to stackoverflow.. what im tring to do is when break statement is exectue i need to jump to the Method1 and run the forloop.Im using C# 4.0

Comment: Saying “jump to the Method1” does not tell us what result you are trying to achieve. We cannot help until we know that.

Answer (score 0):

> i need to know how to jump into the 1st for loop when the break statement is execute.

Have you heard of a little keyword called `return`?

This will not "jump into" the outer method; it will quit the inner one and resume at the currently elapsed place in the outer method's loop.

If you need something else, please explain.

Comment: yeah i heard return keyword..if the condition is true is there any way to directly go back to the forloop which is inside the Method1 rather than using break statement.

Comment: `return` will exit `Method2` immediately. Did you read what I wrote yet?